# Entity Framework One-To-Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

First of all I have these two models to store a post in two tables one for shared data and the other contains cultured data for English and Arabic

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Featured { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostContent> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class PostContent
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post{ set; get; }
}
```

Mapping

```
public class PostMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        ToTable("Posts");
    }
}

public class PostContentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PostContent>
{
    public PostContentMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasRequired(p => p.Post).WithMany(p => p.Contents).HasForeignKey(p=>p.PostId);
        ToTable("PostContents");
    }
}
```

I have two questions

1- Is these models are connected properly. Is there something else I need to do ?

2- I need to select all Posts with their contents where the culture of the content 'en' for example. I used this:

```
var res = context.Posts.Include(p => p.Contents.Single(c => c.Culture.Equals("en")));
```

and have this error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.Parameter name: path

Answer (score 1):

If you know you are **not** going to support more than two cultures then I would just add to your Post class.

```
 public class Post
 {

    public Post()
    {
        Contents = new List<PostContent>();
    }
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Featured { get; set; }
    public int? EnglishContentId { get;set;}
    public int? ArabicContentId { get;set;}

    PostContent EnglishContent {get;set;}
    PostContent ArabicContent {get;set;}

 }

public class PostContent
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string Culture { get; set; }/*This property is not required*/

}

    public class PostMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        ToTable("Posts");
        HasOptional(p => p.EnglishContent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p=>p.EnglishContentId);
        HasOptional(p => p.ArabicContent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p=>p.ArabicContentId);
    }
}

public class PostContentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PostContent>
{
    public PostContentMap()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        ToTable("PostContents");
    }
}
```

The Above design will simplify your design and queries, will improve the performance alot.

But if you might have to support more cultures then you got the design and mapping right.

As far as EF 5, include does not allow filters, but I am not sure about EF 6.0 
atleast you can get all posts that have english contents as follows

Add `using System.Data.Entity;`

```
var res = context.Posts.Include(p => p.Contents).Where(c => c.Contents.Any(cp=>cp.Culture.Equals("en")));
```

Comment: Suppose I have only tow cultures. What will change in my mapping?

Comment: Add `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Edited the answer to show full mapping details incase you just have to support two cultures only.

Comment: I have this error .. Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key.